# Как сделать HUD поверх окошечка C#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать подобный HUD и наложить поверх чужого окошка? Совсем здорово, если будет пример с исходниками.

Comment: сделать окно, которое будет "повер всех окон" и убрать у него заголовок. Потом добавить несклоко компонентов для отображения текста и настроить шрифты.

Comment: Какой UI-фреймворк? Окно ваше или чужое?

Comment: @VladD, окно чужое

Comment: @KoVadim, таких окошечек маленьких около 10, но кажется смысл понятен. и прозрачность соответственно. нет ли примера?

Comment: думаю, что пример Вам не поможет, так как это все можно накликать мышкой в редакторе форм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал тупо в лоб. Прозрачная форма, на которой panels(а на их labels). Их можно двигать и т.д. Получилось очень неплохо. Можно закрывать вопрос.